# Loop Through two different directories using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want loop through all files from two different directories. The problem is that the DIR function doesn't work properly if I want use it simultaneously on two folders. This is my code:

```
Sub LoopThroughAllFiles()

Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim mySourcePath As String
Dim mySourceFile As String
Dim myDestinationPath As String
Dim myDestinationFile As String

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  mySourcePath = "C:\Source\"
  myDestinationPath = "C:\Destination\"
  prefix = "target_"

  mySourcePath = mySourcePath
  myDestinationPath = myDestinationPath

  If mySourcePath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings
  If myDestinationPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  mySourceFile = Dir(mySourcePath)
  myDestinationFile = Dir(myDestinationPath)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While mySourceFile <> "" And myDestinationFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=mySourcePath & mySourceFile)
  Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myDestinationPath & myDestinationFile)
'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents


'Save and Close Workbook
 wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
 wb2.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

'Get next file name
  mySourceFile = Dir
  myDestinationFile = Dir
  Loop

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The idea is that I want copy one sheet from a source excel in a destination excel. This for every excel in source and destination folder. The destination and source excels have the same name (to make it easier).

I don't have any knowledge about VBA, so any hint about modify this simple code would be very helpfull.

Comment: Here is where you lose it:
  mySourceFile = Dir
  myDestinationFile = Dir. 
In what way could the same Dir diffentiate between source and destination?

Comment: Yes I know that the problem are those lines of code but I cannot understand how differentiate between source and destination. Any hint?

Comment: Do the source and destination files have matching /similar names? (ex.: `my_filename_source.xlsx` and `my_filename_destination.xlsx`)

Comment: Basically I can use any name convention that make the job easier. At the moment they have the same name.

Comment: You cannot nest two Dir() loops - create a function to list the files in a direcory into (eg) a Collection, and then compare the two collections you get back from that function.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working. I have a class named "DirectoryLooper". This performs the Dir for each folder separately and makes the comparison earlier. The one flaw in this, that also exists in your code is if the folders have different number of files. Then both your code and my code will terminate when the folder with less files gets to the last file.

```
Private FilePath_ As String
Private fileArray() As String
Private fileIndex As Long

Public Property Let FilePath(ByVal FilePath As String)
    FilePath_ = FilePath
End Property
Public Property Get FilePath() As String
    FilePath = FilePath_
End Property
Public Property Get NumberFiles() As String
    NumberFiles = fileIndex
End Property

Public Sub SetDir()
    Dim fileLoop As String

    fileIndex = 0
    fileLoop = Dir(FilePath_)

    Do While fileLoop <> ""
        ReDim Preserve fileArray(0 To fileIndex) As String
        fileArray(fileIndex) = fileLoop
        fileIndex = fileIndex + 1
        fileLoop = Dir
    Loop
End Sub

Public Function ReturnFile(ndxOfFiles As Long)
    ReturnFile = fileArray(ndxOfFiles)
End Function
```

Then in the main module, here is the pertinent parts of your code with my additions.

```
Sub LoopThroughAllFiles()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim dirOne As DirectoryLooper
    Dim dirTwo As DirectoryLooper
    Dim ndxFiles As Long
    Dim ndxCount As Long

    Set dirOne = New DirectoryLooper
    Set dirTwo = New DirectoryLooper

    dirOne.FilePath = "C:\SourceFolder\"
    dirTwo.FilePath = "C:\DestinationFolder\"

    dirOne.SetDir
    dirTwo.SetDir

    If dirOne.NumberFiles < dirTwo.NumberFiles Then
         ndxCount = dirOne.NumberFiles - 1
    Else
         ndxCount = dirTwo.NumberFiles - 1
    End If

    ndxFiles = 0
    Do While ndxFiles <= ndxCount

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=dirOne.FilePath & dirOne.ReturnFile(ndxFiles))
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=dirTwo.FilePath & dirTwo.ReturnFile(ndxFiles))

        DoEvents

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        wb2.Close SaveChanges:=True

        DoEvents

        ndxFiles = ndxFiles + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```